# What's the difference when you put a dot in numbers?

Tags: c, integer, division

The program should read 5 numbers from the user. Then it has to draw 5 'lines' according to the rate of this numbers. At the biggest number it has to draw 20 ' * '-s and for every other number it has to draw less ' * '-s in proportion to the biggest number.

There's a program which can check if my code is correct, and I tried a lot of things to make it work, but I always got bad result (right side on the picture). Then I was checking the solution of similar exercises and I found that the only difference is that, in the soutions there's a dot after the defined number

```
#define SEGMENT 20.
```

And when I changed just this one thing in my code it worked correctly (left side on the picture). Can someone explain why does it make such a huge difference and why it's working without dot too with some inputs?
Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PCS 5
#define SEGMENT 20
//The only difference in the line above
//#define SEGMENT 20.

int main(void) {
    double nums[PCS];
    int max;
    //Reding the five numbers and finding the biggest value
    for(int i = 0; i < PCS; i++) {
        scanf("%lf", &nums[i]);
        if(i == 0 || max < nums[i]) {
            max = nums[i];
        }
    }
    //Calcualte the rate for the lines
    double rate = SEGMENT / max;
    //Print the lines
    for(int i = 0; i < PCS; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < (int)(nums[i]*rate); j++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `20` is an `int` literal. `20.` is a `double` literal. Integer arithmetic always give integer results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In context of this statement

```
double rate = SEGMENT / max;
```

`20` is an integer.  Hence the expression `20 / max` is also an integer with remainder dropped before being assigned to `rate`

`20.` is the same as `20.0` - it's a floating point real value.  Hence, `20.0 / max` gets evaluated as a real number (with `max` getting effectively promoted from integer to float before the division operation is applied).  And the result of that expression is directly assigned to `rate` without any rounding.

If it helps, you can avoid the floating point computation (and all the weirdness that goes with fp) by doing integer math and having the division operation performed as the last step of your calculation.

That is, instead of this:

```
#define SEGMENT 20.0
...
double rate = SEGMENT / max;
...
    for(int j = 0; j < (int)(nums[i]*rate); j++) {
```

This:

```
#define SEGMENT 20
...
    for(int j = 0; j < (int)(nums[i]*SEGMENT)/max; j++) {
```

This keeps your math in the integer space and should still work. (Disclaimer: `nums` is still an array of double, so the expression `(nums[i]*20)/max` is still a floating point value, but it's not going to incur a rounding error.

Comment: So if I make operations with only integers, then the result will be always an integer, but changing one of them to floting point value, in this case the SEGMENT will result a floting point value what can be assinged correctly to the double, right?

Comment: And if I leave SEGMENT as 20 and changed max's type to double the result would be correct too, if I understand correctly

Comment: Correct.  But see my updated answer on you can avoid doing any floating point altogether.  When you are drawing a precise number of things (stars, pixels, elements), avoiding floating point is easy. (ala "do division last")

Comment: I just noticed `nums` is a double array as well. So the above still works, but the expression `(nums[i]*20)/max` is still a floating point, but with no rounding errors. Hence, you have to keep the cast back to int.

Answer (score 2):

When you divide an `int` by an `int` you get `int` (truncated);

```
7 / 2 == 3
7 / 2.0 == 3.5 (as well as 7.0 / 2)
```

In you code `20.` is just a shorthand for `20.0`